# How to get the original sample pitch knowing how the sample is interpolated at a given pitch?

Tags: sampling, pitch, pcm, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to "reverse engineering" a sample-based synth from the 90's
*(an Ensoniq SQ1, which uses a OTIS chip for the samples; if you're interested you can find the manual of both on the web)* but i think i lack the theory to complete this step.

### What i know and have:

I have the original sampled "instruments", and a table taken from the firmware with data about the samples: start, loop, end, midi note limits, etc, and a 16bit word (**wX**, from now) which is somewhat related to the sample pitch.

The parts of the OTIS chip which is relevant to the question are:

- an *accumulator register* (**accum**), which is a 20bit integer,9bit fractional 29bits register where the integer part is the physical memory address of a sample
- a *frequency counter registed* (**FC**), which is a 6bit integer,9bit fractional 15bits register.
- in that synth, the OTIS samplerate is 29761 Hz.

When a note needs to be played, the main CPU writes a value in **accum** which is the Sample start address, and a value in **FC** which is somehow a function of the note played and **wX**.

To play the sound the OTIS loads the sample at the address in the accum integer part, the next one at that address+1, and interpolate them using the **accum** fractional part to produce the final sample.

After other sound processing not relevant here, it finally adds **FC** to **accum**, and then restart the cycle.

#### Examples:

Playng a A4 (440Hz) note:

- for Sample1 **wX**=`C1C7`, **FC**=`05EA` (1,478516)
- for Sample2 **wX**=`C400`, **FC**=`06BA` (1,681641)

Playng a C4 (261.626Hz) note:

- for Sample1 **wX**=`C1C7`, **FC**=`0384` (0,878906)
- for Sample2 **wX**=`C400`, **FC**=`0400` (1,000000)

### -EDIT-

Inspired by Justme answer, i've found that if i divide the note frequency by **FC** (so, "removing" the played note) i get a "constant" (given a bit of approximation):

- Sample 1: (A4)440/1,478516=297,5956973 - (C4)261.626/0,878906=297,671839
- Sample 2: (A4)440/1,681641=261,6491867 - (C4)261.626/1,000000=261,6255653

So, this "constant" and **wX** are "the same thing". Maybe **wX** is expressed in cents, or made to be used with a midi note #, or some sort of pre-calculated value related to the OTIS samplerate...

### The question:

I'm able to know the value of **FC** for each note played for each sample, i also know the value of **wX** for each sample and i think that with the data i have i *should* be able to find what **wX** means and so what is the original sampled instrument pitch.

But i don't know how.

How can i get the original samples pitch?
What the word **wX** means?

Comment: It looks like **wX** points to an address in ROM.  **FC** is the increment for the phase accumulator and is proportional to the frequency of the note. Do you have a bit copy of the ROM?  I'm trying to understand what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to turn these one-shot sampled notes into a .wav file with loop points?  It's looks like you know the initial pointer value and the pointer increment.  Do you know what the loop points are?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: i'm sure at 90% that **wX** is not a pointer. Yes, i have the ROM samples as a whole 8bit CPM wav file,, yes, i want to use the single samples as wavs, the start, loop and end point for each sample is in the same table where **wX** is, and i just want to know how to "tune" each sample, which is the last info i need.

Comment: Perhaps the table is very large, but can you post some of it, so that we can try to see a pattern.  I am **still** suspicious that **wX** is a pointer.  Also, I suspect that **FC** has 10 fractional bits instead of 9.  Just from the data you displayed above.

Comment: Sure: [GDrive sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gQSihp3ugSxAMS_rz3_QMg0PiW93XatrI2qd6-PHzYo/edit?usp=sharing). And [The OTIS PDF manual](https://www.dosdays.co.uk/media/ensoniq/es5505%20-%20OTIS.pdf)

Comment: About the data examples and **FC**: **FC** is a 15bit **left aligned** register, so 0x400 "minus" the rightmost bit become 0x200, and with a 9 bit fractional part you get 1.0

Comment: I looked at both documents and there does not appear to have any reference to a symbol "**wX**".  But I was able to make use of the references in sections 2.2 and 4.1 and 4.2 .  This is a standard sample playback machine with looping and linear interpolation.  And, yes, there are 9 fractional bits in the accumulator (and 20 integer bits that *do* contain the address in the waveform RAM.  Do you understand what is going on in those three sections of the OTIS.pdf manual?

Comment: Then, in that other document, the SQ1 Sample Table, the stuff in column F must be an index to a table of pointers and other data.  Do you know what that might look like?

Comment: **wX** is D1 D2 in the google sheet. I didn't thougth to share it so i was just using wX here in this question,

If you look at the "main sheet - data analysis" you'll see how the data in the table are used, with some comment by me during the years. Column F in the table is the upper note limit, which means that after than note the next sample will be used.

About the manual section, yes i understand them. Those are what i tried to describe in the question body, here. My english is bad, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

That's how many other sound chips work, both wavetable and FM synthesizers, from C64 SID to Yamaha FM synthesis and these Ensoniq-type sound cards like Gravis UltraSound which is supposed to base on Ensoniq OTTO.

As there is 12 notes per octave and octave means doubling of frequency, we know that between two neighbouring notes there is a factor of 2^(1/12) or 1.05946. As 100 cents is also difference between two notes, an octave is 1200 cents.

If you take the sample 2, you know it has been recorded at C4 and sampling rate of 29761 Hz because the accumulator increment is 1.0 (0x400).

We can verify that because between C4 and A4 they are 9 notes apart and so the factor is 2^(9/12) or 1.68179, which matches within rounding tolerance with the 1722/1024 you already know so 1722 is A if C is 1024. Also 1200*log2(1722/1024) is 900 cents.

What you basically want is to use that formula in reverse, and for the sampling rates.

For the sample 1, it is clear that there is no note you can push which would give a value of 1.000 for the playback increment, so it is not originally sampled at 29761 Hz to begin with, but some other sampling rate.

If you try playing it at C4, it runs at 0.8789 speed if sampling rate is 29761 Hz, so it must mean C4 sampling rate for that sample is 26157 Hz.

But you don't really know if the original sample has been sampled by using note C4 and sampled at 26157 Hz, or has some other note and sampling rate used. For example if you transpose 3 notes down the sampling rate will be almost exactly 22000 Hz (not 22050 Hz but it could be, some people refer to 22050 as 22kHz, and the error is only 4 cents which is usually below threshold of noticing it).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, i learned a lot. *But you don't really know if the original sample has been sampled by using note C4 ...* I think that this information is somehow stored in the **wX** 16bit word, and if we get what it means, we know how to handle the original sample. Don't you?

Comment: @Parduz I would think so - but that xW value is not directly used by the OTTO, the microprocessor running the program code and uses the xW value to calculate the FC. You need to reverse engineer the MCU/CPU ROMs.

Comment: exactly. If i get what **wX** means, i'll get how the MC68K calculate **FC**. Pls see the question edit.